# Why does moment.duration for a date with a diff of a month not return month

Tags: momentjs, duration

I create a moment date then add one month, if I moment.diff I get 1 month, but when I create a duration it does not return one month.

```
const diffInMillis = this.getDiff(this.state.term.startDate, this.state.term.endDate);
    const diffInMonths = this.getDiff(this.state.term.startDate, this.state.term.endDate, 'months');
    const diffDuration = moment.duration(diffInMillis);
    const diffDurationMonths = diffDuration.months();
    const diffDurationDays = diffDuration.days();
```

[Code pen of issue](https://codepen.io/Lazzzza/pen/gOpmxqz)

Comment: Its not that clear, can you give us what is the output you are expecting also the inputs?

Comment: So I a have date todays date, then I add a month with moment, I need to get the duration in months allowing for user adding a month and one day, so output would be: Term is 3 months and two days

Comment: "allowing for user adding a month and one day, so output would be: Term is 3 months and two days" this part is still not clear.